# PyTorch - multiplying tensor with scalar results in zero vector

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have no idea why the result is all 0 with tensor. Anything wrong here?

```
>>> import torch
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import math

>>> torch.__version__
'0.4.1'
>>> np.__version__
'1.15.4'

>>> torch.arange(0, 10, 2) *-(math.log(10000.0) / 10)
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> np.arange(0, 10, 2) *-(math.log(10000.0) / 10)
array([-0.        , -1.84206807, -3.68413615, -5.52620422, -7.3682723 ])

>>> torch.arange(0, 10, 2)
tensor([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
>>> np.arange(0, 10, 2)
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Comment: Results in `tensor([-0.0000, -1.8421, -3.6841, -5.5262, -7.3683])` for me, 
v`0.4.0a0+3749c58`

Comment: Python version 3.7.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the comment when using **0.4.0** get the same results as with numpy:

```
tensor([-0.0000, -1.8421, -3.6841, -5.5262, -7.3683])
```

However with `0.4.1` I'm getting a zero vector too.

The reason for this is that `torch.arange(0, 10, 2)` returns a tensor of type `float` for **0.4.0** while it returns a tensor of type `long` for **0.4.1**.

So casting your tensor to `float` should work for you:

```
torch.arange(0, 10, 2).float() *-(math.log(10000.0) / 10)
```

Multiplying `long` and `float` works by heavy rounding, as the result is still a tensor of type `long`. So when converting a `FloatTensor` to a `LongTensor` values between -1 and 1 will be rounded to 0.

Since `-(math.log(10000.0) / 10)` results in `-0.9210340371976183` your result is `0`. So effectively `-0.9210340371976183` is converted to type `long` before multiplying. But when converting it will be round down to `0`, see this example:

```
t = torch.tensor((-(math.log(10000.0) / 10)))
print('FloatTensor:', t)
print('Converted to Long:', t.long())
```

Outout:

```
FloatTensor: tensor(-0.9210)
Converted to Long: tensor(0)
```

Thus:

```
torch.arange(0, 10, 2).float() *-(math.log(10000.0) / 10)
```

becomes:

```
torch.arange(0, 10, 2).float() * 0
```

Therefore you get a tensor of zeros as result.

---

*Some more examples:*

If you multiply it with a value between 1 and 2, lets say 1.7, it will always been rounded down to 1:

```
t = torch.tensor(range(5), dtype=torch.long)
print(t)
print(t * 1.7)
```

Output:

```
tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

And similarly when multiplying with `2.7` results in an effective multiplication of `2`:

```
t = torch.tensor(range(5), dtype=torch.long)
print(t)
print(t * 2.7)
```

Output:

```
tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
tensor([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8])
```

Comment: Yes. Can you elaborate a bit more on why is that? Without .float(), I add/minus 1,2... to (math.log(10000.0) / 10) and will get something like tensor([ 0, -2, -4, -6, -8]), tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), tensor([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])...

Comment: @Kuo Thanks, I added some more examples to make the behaviour of multiplication `long` * `float` more clear!